# Get App Name in Swift

Tags: cocoa, swift

How do I get the application name in Swift?

Googling gave me this:

```
[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleName"];
```

I converted it to Swift; error - method doesn't exist:

```
NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary.objectForKey("CFBundleName")
```

Answer (score 156, accepted):

This should work:

```
NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary!["CFBundleName"] as! String
```

`infoDictionary` is declared as a `var infoDictionary: [NSObject : AnyObject]!` so you have to unwrap it, access it as a Swift dictionary (rather than use `objectForKey`), and, as the result is an `AnyObject`, cast it.

**Update Swift 3 (Xcode 8 beta 2)**

Always better to use constants (and optionals) where possible, too:

```
Bundle.main.infoDictionary?[kCFBundleNameKey as String] as? String
```

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks it's pretty ironic Full Decent recommending a force cast?

Comment: CFBundleName might not always be the name of the app shown to the user. See my answer below how to get the name of the app shown under the icon on the home screen.

Comment: The answers given by @VadimBulavin and MariánČerný are better, also force casts are not idiomatic

Answer (score 66):

I believe this solution is more elegant. What's more, using `object(forInfoDictionaryKey:)` is [encouraged by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/bundle/1408696-object):

> "Use of this method is preferred over other access methods because it returns the localized value of a key when one is available."

```
extension Bundle {
    var displayName: String? {
        return object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleDisplayName") as? String
    }
}
```

Accessing bundle display name:

```
if let displayName = Bundle.main.displayName {
    print(displayName)
}
```

Comment: @ixany, here is the quote from [Apple's Q&A](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1892/_index.html) that proves that `CFBundleDisplayName` is the correct value: _"The app name on the iPhone home screen comes from the CFBundleDisplayName (or "Bundle display name", the human-readable string in Xcode)"_

Comment: It should be `CFBundleDisplayName`. But if not available, it should fall back to `CFBundleName`. See my answer below.

Answer (score 58):

I have created a simple extension to get the app name that is shown under the icon on the Home screen.

By default, apps only have `CFBundleName` set. Some apps, however, set `CFBundleDisplayName` *(The user-visible name of the bundle)* to change the title under the app icon. Adding spaces is often the case, e.g. bundle name "ExampleApp" could have bundle display name set to "Example App".

```
extension Bundle {
    /// Application name shown under the application icon.
    var applicationName: String? {
        object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleDisplayName") as? String ??
            object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleName") as? String
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let appName = Bundle.main.applicationName
```

Comment: This should be the preferred answer. Not only does it handle both cases, but it does it without force-wrapping,  a pestilence which should never be in sample code.

Comment: Definitely the preferred answer!

Answer (score 23):

Same answer in **Swift 4.2**

```
extension Bundle {
    class var applicationName: String {

        if let displayName: String = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleDisplayName"] as? String {
            return displayName
        } else if let name: String = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleName"] as? String {
            return name
        }
        return "No Name Found"
    }
}
```

you can use it like below

```
Bundle.applicationName
```

OR, An other way would be to avoid static or class method or property but to add to instance level.

```
extension Bundle {
    var applicationName: String {

        if let displayName: String = self.infoDictionary?["CFBundleDisplayName"] as? String {
            return displayName
        } else if let name: String = self.infoDictionary?["CFBundleName"] as? String {
            return name
        }
        return "No Name Found"
    }
}
```

and all it like following

```
Bundle.main.applicationName
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 13):

**Swift 4**

`let appName = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleDisplayName") as! String`

Comment: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Answer (score 6):

simple way:

```
let appName = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary?[kCFBundleNameKey as String] as? String
```

convenient way:

```
extension NSBundle {
    class func mainInfoDictionary(key: CFString) -> String? {
        return self.mainBundle().infoDictionary?[key as String] as? String
    }
}
print(NSBundle.mainInfoDictionary(kCFBundleNameKey))
```

**kCFBundleNameKey** – Standard Info.plist key, see more in **CFBundle**

Answer (score 6):

1. All answers that just return `CFBundleName` will often not return the name the user expects, as if bundles have a `CFBundleDisplayName`, then this key is displayed by Finder, system frameworks, and most other apps.
2. Most answers just directly access the info dictionary but info dictionaries can be localized by string files and when accessing them directly, this localization is also ignored and thus again a wrong name may be returned, as Finder will display the localized name.
3. While `CFBundleDisplayName` is optional in `Info.plist` files, `CFBundleName` actually isn't, but if you forget to add it, nothing will break in your system, so you have a corrupt info dict, yet most users will probably never notice and in that case the code most answers may not return anything meaningful at all.

Here's my solution (Swift 3):

```
private
func stripFileExtension ( _ filename: String ) -> String {
    var components = filename.components(separatedBy: ".")
    guard components.count > 1 else { return filename }
    components.removeLast()
    return components.joined(separator: ".")
}

func nameOfApp ( ) -> String {
    let bundle = Bundle.main
    if let name =  bundle.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleDisplayName")
        ?? bundle.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: kCFBundleNameKey as String),
        let stringName = name as? String
        { return stringName }

    let bundleURL = bundle.bundleURL
    let filename = bundleURL.lastPathComponent
    return stripFileExtension(filename)
}
```

How is this solution better?

1. It will check `CFBundleDisplayName` first and only fall back to `CFBundleName` if not present.
2. The `object()` method always operates on the localized version of the info dictionary, so if a localization exists, it will automatically be used.
3. If neither `CFBundleDisplayName` nor `CFBundleName` exist in the dictionary, the code falls back to just using the bundle filename on disk without the extension (so "My Cool App.app" will be "My Cool App"), this is a fallback so that this function will never return `nil`.

Answer (score 6):

// Returns app's name

```
public static var appDisplayName: String? {
    if let bundleDisplayName = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleDisplayName") as? String {
        return bundleDisplayName
    } else if let bundleName = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleName") as? String {
        return bundleName
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
let appDisplayName = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleName"] as? String
```

It's optional, so put it in if let or guard statement.

Answer (score 4):

This one works for me in **Swift 4.2**

```
guard let dictionary = Bundle.main.infoDictionary else { return "" }
if let version: String = dictionary["CFBundleDisplayName"] as? String {
   return version
} else {
   return ""
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked for me in Xcode 11.0 and Swift 5

```
 let bundleID = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier
 let bundleInfoDict: NSDictionary = Bundle.main.infoDictionary! as NSDictionary
 let appName = bundleInfoDict["CFBundleName"] as! String
 print(bundleID!)
 print(appName)
```

Answer (score 2):

This should be more like what you are looking for:

```
let infoDictionary: NSDictionary = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary as NSDictionary!
let appName: NSString = infoDictionary.objectForKey("CFBundleName") as NSString

NSLog("Name \(appName)")
```

There may still be a better way to do this but it at least returns the app name correctly in my very limited testing...

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
extension Bundle {
    var displayName: String {
        let name = object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleDisplayName") as? String
        return name ?? object(forInfoDictionaryKey: kCFBundleNameKey as String) as! String
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let bundleInfoDict: NSDictionary = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary!
let appName = bundleInfoDict["CFBundleName"] as String
```

Answer (score 1):

This one works perfect for me

```
let appName = NSBundle.mainBundle().objectForInfoDictionaryKey("CFBundleDisplayName") as! String
```

Answer (score 1):

```swift
// Bundle+appName.swift

extension Bundle {
    var appName: String {
        object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleDisplayName") as? String ??
        object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleName") as? String ??
        ""
    }
}

// Usage (non optional)

let appName = Bundle.main.appName
```

Answer (score 0):

**For swift 5, iOS 13***

As mentioned before, it‘s an optional, so put it in a guard statement. I do this using a struct:

```
struct Model {
    struct ProgVariablen{
        static var appBundleName:String {
            get {guard Bundle.main.infoDictionary != nil else {return ""}
                return Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleName"] as! String
            }//end get
        }//end computed property
        static var appBundleShortVersion:String {
            get {guard Bundle.main.infoDictionary != nil else {return ""}
                return Bundle.main.infoDictionary ["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as! String
            }//end get
        }//end computed property
        static var appBundleBuild:String {
            get {guard Bundle.main.infoDictionary != nil else {return ""}
                return Bundle.main.infoDictionary["CFBundleVersion"] as! String
        }//end get
    }//end computed property

    //initialsieren der Variablen
    init(
         appBundleName:String,
         appBundleShortVersion:String,
         appBundleBuild:String,
         )
    {
        // do here nothing for 'let'
        // do here nothing for 'computed properties'
        // your other ‘var’ are here like:
        // ProgVariablen.var1 = var1
    }//end init
    }//end struct ProgVariablen
}//end struct Model
```

**Usage:**

```
print("Model.ProgVariablen.appBundleName: '\(Model.ProgVariablen.appBundleName)'")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
extension NSApplication {
    
    static var name: String {
        Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: kCFBundleNameKey as String) as? String ?? ProcessInfo.processInfo.processName
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this one,

```
let bundleID = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleIdentifier
```

Comment: That will return the bundle identifier, not the name (ie `com.mycompany.appname`)

Comment: You can access to NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary to read the plist configuration file of the project

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-102070

Comment: CFBundleIdentifier purpose is different.